# Gnome javascript documentation

Tags: javascript, shell, gnome

I'm trying to dive into Gnome shell extensions development but I'm a little bit confused at the moment.
I can't seem to find a proper documentation about GJS library. For example I want to know at least what imports are available and members/method of classes without that I can only rely on existing extensions code, not too much.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To start writing GNOME Shell Extensions, I would recommend you to start looking the [Shell Extensions wiki page](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions). There you will find links to tutorials, as well as guidelines.

With respect to modules available, you have everything that is available via [GObject Instrospection](https://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection).  In order to get familiar with this, you can take a look the [explained demos](http://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/unstable/).  For API docuementation, you can go to [Platform Overview](http://developer.gnome.org/platform-overview/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert myself, but based on my experience patching an extension, most of the utility are based on Clutter in which GObject Introspection expose the API to JavaScript. Unfortunately I cannot find the API documentation for the shell itself. The closest I can get is the JavaScript for the shell at `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/` which (for me) is quite enough as an extension would probably modify JavaScript object at runtime rather than calling it's function.